# Gradle ignoring elements in custom POM due to namespace polution of plugins

Tags: java, maven, gradle, pom.xml

I'm trying to customize my pom as shown in [this thread](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/new-publishing-model-and-pom-customization-via-xmlprovider/6111). My attempt looks like this:

```
def pomConfig = {
    // ...
    licenses {
        license {
            name "LGPL 3.0"
            url "https://gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0"
            distribution 'repo'
        }
    }
}
publishing {
   publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            pom.withXml {
                asNode().children().last() + pomConfig
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this shows as the following in the (invalid) pom:

```
<licenses>
    <name>LGPL 3.0</name>
    <url>https://gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0</url>
    <distribution>repo</distribution>
</licenses>
```

When I change the name in gradle from `license` to something else, it works like a charm. E.g. when I rename it to `liecense`, I get the following xml:

```
<licenses>
    <liecense>
        <name>LGPL 3.0</name>
        <url>https://gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </liecense>
</licenses>
```

I tried with both gradle 4.2.1 and gradle 4.3.1, both the same behaviour.

How can I get gradle to add a `license` xml element?

#### Update:

I found out that I'm using a plugin that has a configuration within a `license {}` block. Disabling the plugin solves the problem. However **I wonder if there is any way to have the plugin active and the `pomConfig` working at the same time?** I tried writing `"license" {` instead, but it doesn't solve the problem. Applying the plugin after defining `pomConfig` isn't helpfull either.